# Ios Parse Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am programming an IOS app that will use parse to login a user. Using storyboard I have the login button connected to another view controller with the push segue. Whether the username and password are correct the button selection always goes to the new view controller.  I might be doing this all wrong. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:self.emailField.text password:self.passwordField.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {

                                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signIn" sender:nil];
                                    } else {
                                        // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                                    }
                                }];
```

}

Comment: Do you have a segue from the first view controller to the next view controller or from the button to the next view controller?

Comment: from the button to the next view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you connected the button right to the next view controller in your storyboard. Here's what you need to do:

1. Select the first view controller and create a segue to the second one, NOT from the button, from the first view controller.
2. In the inspector give the segue an identifier (i.e. "loginSegue").
3. Create an IBAction for your button by control-dragging the button in the storyboard to the .m file of your first view controller. In that new method you can add the login code:

   ```
   [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:self.emailField.text 
   password:self.passwordField.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) 

           {
                                                   if (!error) {

                                                   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:nil];
                                               } else {
                                                   // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                                               }
                                           }];
   ```